# finding members who have not renewed for current year

Tags: sql, sql-server

Membership table contains 1 record per member per year (simplified for this example.

[image]

I want the 2013 members who have not renewed for 2014. This is as close as I've come logically but I get null results

```
SELECT  Users.UserID
      , YEAR(Membership.MemYear) AS MemYear
      , Users.MailTo
      , Users.StreetAddress
      , Users.Address2
      , Users.City
      , StateLookup.State
      , Users.Zip
FROM Users INNER JOIN Membership 
ON Users.UserID = Membership.UserID 
INNER JOIN StateLookup 
ON Users.StateID = StateLookup.StateID 
where YEAR(Membership.MemYear) = '2013' 
and not exists 
(SELECT  Users.UserID, YEAR(Membership.MemYear) AS MemYear
       , Users.MailTo, Users.StreetAddress, Users.Address2
       , Users.City, StateLookup.State, Users.Zip
FROM Users INNER JOIN Membership AS Membership_1 
ON Users.UserID = Membership_1.UserID 
INNER JOIN StateLookup 
ON Users.StateID = StateLookup.StateID 
where YEAR(Membership_1.MemYear)='2014')
```

Help appreciated!

Comment: why do you need the state lookup, is 'UserID' not unique?

Comment: What is the data type of MemYear column in Member table ??

Answer (score 1):

I think if 'UserID' is unique you could just do this.

```
SELECT Users.UserID  
  , YEAR(Membership.MemYear) AS MemYear  
  , Users.MailTo  
  , Users.StreetAddress  
  , Users.Address2  
  , Users.City  
  , StateLookup.State 
  , Users.Zip  
 FROM Users INNER JOIN Membership   
 ON Users.UserID = Membership.UserID   
 INNER JOIN StateLookup   
 ON Users.StateID = StateLookup.StateID   
 WHERE Membership.MemYear = '2013'   
 AND Users.UserID NOT IN  
   (SELECT UserID FROM Membership WHERE MemYear = '2014');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `MAX(MemYear)` to find people who have a maximum MemYear of 2013. That means they were active in 2013 and haven't renewed.

```
SELECT Users.UserID
      , Users.MailTo
      , Users.StreetAddress
      , Users.Address2
      , Users.City
      , StateLookup.State
      , Users.Zip
FROM Users 
INNER JOIN Membership 
    ON Users.UserID = Membership.UserID 
INNER JOIN StateLookup 
    ON Users.StateID = StateLookup.StateID 
GROUP BY Users.UserID
      , Users.MailTo
      , Users.StreetAddress
      , Users.Address2
      , Users.City
      , StateLookup.State
      , Users.Zip
HAVING MAX(YEAR(Membership.MemYear)) = 2013
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the bottom portion of your query as follows:

You forgot to reference back to the other layer of your query. Assuming the rest of your query is fine, this should fix that problem.

```
SELECT Users.UserID,
       YEAR(Membership.MemYear) AS MemYear,
       Users.MailTo,
       Users.StreetAddress,
       Users.Address2,
       Users.City,
       StateLookup.State,
       Users.Zip
  FROM Users
 INNER JOIN Membership
    ON Users.UserID = Membership.UserID
 INNER JOIN StateLookup
    ON Users.StateID = StateLookup.StateID
 where YEAR(Membership.MemYear) = '2013'
   and not exists (SELECT x.UserID,
               YEAR(Membership.MemYear) AS MemYear,
               x.MailTo,
               x.StreetAddress,
               x.Address2,
               x.City,
               StateLookup.State,
               x.Zip
          FROM Users x
         INNER JOIN Membership AS Membership_1
            ON x.UserID = Membership_1.UserID
         INNER JOIN StateLookup
            ON x.StateID = StateLookup.StateID
         where YEAR(Membership_1.MemYear) = '2014'
           and x.UserID = Users.UserID)
```

Comment: As an fyi it doesn't matter what you select in the select list of the exists subquery, you might have been thinking you were using an IN subquery. Another way to fix that query would be to change "not exists" to "not in".

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  Users.UserID
      , MemYear 
      , Users.MailTo
      , Users.StreetAddress
      , Users.Address2
      , Users.City
      , StateLookup.State
      , Users.Zip
FROM Users INNER JOIN Membership 
ON Users.UserID = Membership.UserID 
INNER JOIN StateLookup 
ON Users.StateID = StateLookup.StateID 
where Users.UserID  NOT IN 
                      (SELECT UserID
                       FROM Membership
                       where MemYear ='2014')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  Users.UserID
  , YEAR(Membership.MemYear) AS MemYear
  , Users.MailTo
  , Users.StreetAddress
  , Users.Address2
  , Users.City
  , StateLookup.State
  , Users.Zip
FROM Users INNER JOIN Membership ON Users.UserID = Membership.UserID 
INNER JOIN StateLookup ON Users.StateID = StateLookup.StateID 
where YEAR(Membership.MemYear) <= 2013   /* If it Integer you don't need '' */
```

why use subquery?

Comment: I added less then 2013 or equal 2013 and it doesn't include 2014 anyways, make it simple.

Comment: Membership has one record per user per year... meaning your query can return results for people with a year of 2014. Though you don't necessarily need 2nd select statement. I show with `HAVING` instead.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev MY BET, DIDN'T LOOK AT MEMBERSHIP TABLE FOR DUPLICATE NAMES, you right, having clause solves the problem